# Using smart pointers on the mbed

Tags: c++, embedded, mbed

Is there a way to use smart pointers on the [mbed board](http://mbed.org/), together with the mbed libraries? What compiler is needed?

Comment: you can use whatever compiler/language you want.  simply place the .bin file on the virtual flash disk and press reset.  no reason why you should limit yourself to their online compiler.

Answer (score 3):

According to the website, they provide the compiler as an online platform. I can't access it, but assuming it's a somewhat recent version of GCC with C++ enabled, but not so recent that C++11 is an option, you can get smart pointers using TR1.

```
#include <tr1/memory>

std::tr1::shared_ptr< int > smart = std::make_shared( 5 );
```

Ah, now I see they support an "export to external toolchain" option. That should give you the freedom to upgrade GCC. I'm not sure what the minimum is for `tr1::shared_ptr` to be present, but it's likely to be there in any version of GCC 4.x.

If you opt for C++11, it's best to go for the most recent compiler version you can get. You may have to build from source. Be sure to specify the necessary ARM target platform.